# how to use lib files in rails to other module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new in ruby, 
i have folder like this:

```
my-project
 - app
   - controllers
     - api
       - v1
        * api_module.rb
       - v2
 - lib
   * class_a.rb
```

i want to use `class_a.rb` into `api_module.rb`, how can i do this ?

my `api_module.rb` is like this

```
module Api
  module V1
   class ServiceOne < Api::V1::BaseApiController

     def do_something 
       # i want to use here
     end

   end
  end
end
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can't you simply use `ClassA.new` on the place of the comment? You might have to `require 'class_a'` at the top though.

Comment: i was thought so but i can't try or test it until i run the server, i was just one to make sure and know how to do the right one to do this :), i am new for ruby ,:) @3limin4t0r

Comment: You can test it without running the server from the Ruby on Rails console. Execute bundle exec rails c from a terminal in the projects folder should do the trick. You should require class_a in your module to be able to use it like @3limin4t0r said. Is api_module.rb part of your Rails application i.e. is it int the app folder?

Comment: yes correct @Smek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to Define lib file under Lib directory

- lib

  - class_a.rb

Sample Code

```
class ClassA
  def request() #Chose any name of the function
     #TODO: Define the Code here whatever you want
  end
end
```

Now Call this Lib File Wherever you need to use by `LibFileName.new.function_name()` in current case which is `ClassA.new.request()`

```
module Api
   module V1
     class ServiceOne < Api::V1::BaseApiController

        def do_something 
           ClassA.new.request() # Calling the lib file 
        end

     end
   end
end
```

also, Don't miss out to load all lib files with autoload in the `application.rb`.

```
module MyApp
    class Application < Rails::Application
      config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
      config.paths.add Rails.root.join('lib').to_s, eager_load: true
    end
end
```

Otherwise, you will always get an error on a production server while loading lib files.

You can call this lib function in the `rails c` console as well.

Comment: This way you are loading everything from the lib folder you probably do not want that. jhgju77 is just using a single class.

Comment: agreed on @Smek my intension was by this so he can create as many and use them without loading specifically. if he wants to load only one lib file then he can use the require like this `require 'class_a'` or give the specific file name instead of loading the whole directory of lib.

Comment: indeed one could load everything from the lib directory that makes it easier because do not need to load every single class with require. But this could make your application slow if there is a lot of code files in the lib directory so I think it is a good practice to just load the files you need with require.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```rb
require 'class_a'

module Api
  module V1
   class ServiceOne < Api::V1::BaseApiController

     def do_something 
       # i want to use here
     end

   end
  end
end
```

Open a Rails console and call Api::V1::ServiceOne.new.do_something then you should get the expected result.